# Where was this picture made?

Tags: screenshot

Supposed DM message:

[image]

Can someone please tell me if there's any way to know whether this (screen grab posted on twitter) is real or not? ie: is it a picture genuinely taken of a DM or a message, or is there a bit of code in it that points toward it being taken from a @fake message generator' type site? I've my suspicions, and the date is wrong because he's English, and it's been formatted as if he were American. Help settle an argument if possible, please??

Comment: In your image, the spelling of the word `believes` is incorrectly spelt as `beleives`. Except for that there is no clue. To answer your question, AFAIK, it was made in some electronic device like a computer or a mobile or a tablet

Comment: Im saying Fake I know a little about forensics look at both Is an is. Now if He edited the messages using his or her phone. Starting a new sentence would automatically Capitalize the first letter. Now looking at it. It is actually a part of the first paragraph. Unless he just decided to Capitalize one is but not the other look at it. My Two cents.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible to tell unless they've done a particularly poor job of it. It's simply text on a background, how could anybody know?

[image]